Install SSH2 in Ubuntu 22.04 PHP 8.1.27
I am only a novice in Ubuntu, but I am trying to run a PHP script which uses the ssh2_connect() function, but keep getting an error;
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to ftp.xxx.co.uk on port 22                                                                              in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/distcheck/xxx.php on line 2

I have read several tutorials on how to enable ssh2 in Ubuntu and adapted one which looked like it had worked;
sudo apt-get install php8.1-ssh2

then
sudo service apache2 restart

But I still get the same error.
From the commandline if I just type;
SSH2

I get;
  Command 'ssh2' not found, did you mean:
  command 'sshd' from deb openssh-server (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4)
  command 'ss2' from deb python3-pyroute2.core (0.6.4-3ubuntu2)
  command 'ssh1' from deb openssh-client-ssh1 (1:7.5p1-13)
  command 'ssh' from deb openssh-client (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4)
  Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

So, I have tried;
sudo apt install ssh2

But get this;
Package ssh2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ssh2' has no installation candidate

I can see lots of other people have asked similar questions... but I have not found an answer which works for me... so hopefully someone can offer some detailed assistance.
Thanks

Are you sure that server ftp.xxx.co.uk even accepts SSH connections? SSH and FTP are different protocols.

Yes, its one of our suppliers who is retiring their FTP server and have advised us to collect using sFTP. They linked me to the following sites about how to do this;
phpseclib         https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ and https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp
SSH2/SCP class          https://www.sitepoint.com/using-ssh-and-sftp-with-php/

Did you check if the port 22 is open? When closed you cant get a connection on that port.

Try telnet ftp.xxx.co.uk 22 and if you get a timeout the port is propably closed.

I spoke to the supplier and it appears that they are using IP whitelisting, so my test server was being rejected.

I am now able to connect and authenticate using "ssh2_connect($host, $port)".

First install the php ssh2 package with:
sudo apt install php8.1-ssh2

Find out which php.ini you use with:
php --ini

Should be something like /etc/php/php.ini
Open that file and check if there is an entry in the extension part:
extension=ssh2.so

If not. Add the line in the extension part.
Restart Apache:
sudo service apache2 restart

I did not test it, but that should to the job.

Thanks for the help... I amended the /etc/php/cli/php.ini file as this is the one in use and restarted Apache - but still when I type ssh2 at the command line I get;
Command 'ssh2' not found, did you mean:
command 'sshd' from deb openssh-server (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4)
command 'ss2' from deb python3-pyroute2.core (0.6.4-3ubuntu2)
command 'ssh1' from deb openssh-client-ssh1 (1:7.5p1-13)
command 'ssh' from deb openssh-client (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4)
Try: sudo apt install 

I added "extension=ssh2.so" in the Dynamic Extensions section as this was the only "extensions" area I could see.

To check the enabled modules type php -m. The Module should be listed there.

Looks good - it does show ssh2 in the list - however the first line on the list says "PHP Warning: Module "ssh2" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

Ok. Then remove the entry extension=ssh2.so from php.ini again and restart the apache. Try php -m again.

Now I get the list of installed modules and "ssh2" is listed, with no errors... however when I type ssh2 at the command line it says "Command 'ssh2' not found"... should it not just error due to syntax or am I over thinking this? As it appears to be installed I will try a PHP script again to log in to the remote server and see what happens. Many thanks for your help

The module ssh2 is not a cli command. You should now be able to use the php commands in your script. Please read the comments i made on your question too. And consider that you may also need the phpseclib as described in the links you mentioned.

https://phpseclib.com/docs/install

I am now able to connect and authenticate against their sFTP server using "ssh2_connect"... the script does fail with an error "ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/distcheck/xxx.php" - so this is something different - Thanks for all the help so far ;-)

I also tried installing ssh2 in this way, But it show a warning and the module is not listed when I do php -m "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/ssh2.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"

I updated my ansver. You will of course need the php-ssh2 package for your PHP version. In the above case it's php 8.1. This could differ, if you use a other PHP Version.
